# enter accessibility on IE11 windows 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events

I am having a problem with the enter key on IE11.
My code looks like this.

```
$(document).on('change', '.js-jump-to-page', function(e) {
    if ( e.which == 13 ) {
        console.log('Enter');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    ...
    ...
```

when I click on the up or down arrows, immediate fires whatever is outside the scope of the conditional. Seems like is not reading the enter key. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. Whatt does clicking on arrows have to do with the enter key?

Comment: @barmar on accessibility, on a dropdown menu, you are able to select options with down and up keys, and select the option with enter key. So the problem is that when I click the down key, it acts as an enter.

Comment: The `change` event doesn't fill in the `which` property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: That property is only filled in for keyboard events. Even though you're triggering the `change` event with the keyboard, it's not really a keyboard event like `keyup` or `keydown`. It's a separate event that's triggered as a default action after the keyboard event.